# Mysql query to count the row values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Iam working in rails 3. i need count the row values from a mysql table.

In rails 3 i want to write that query in controller.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM #{table_name}
```

is that the correct query method.?

Comment: can you be more specific plz??

Comment: You can get it by using the count method for that Model. For ex: if your model name is User then User.count will fetch the number of rows in users table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count all the rows in a table easily with ActiveRecord. Let's use Post for your table name.

```
@posts = Post.all
@posts.count
```

Or like this:

```
Post.all.count
```